# Script Error 'Invalid Pointer' in Spatial Analyst Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, error

I have ArcGis 10.3 (previously 10.2 version) running on Windows 10 (previously Windows 8). My GIS licence is provide by my company where I have an intership, so I can't just uninstall/install back the logiciel.

So, I have this script error which appears often when I want to use Spatial Analyst Tool or Geoprocessing Tool:

> Line 51, Char 4, Error Invalid Pointer, Code 0, URL
>   file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.3/ArcToolbox/Dlg/MdDlgContent.htm

I look at tons of articles online and did all their proposed solutions (put Internet Explorer as default browser, enable Active X control in security, clear roaming and local history of ArcTool Box in my AppData, upload a 'new patch version' of MdDlgContent.htm in my ArcGIS file provide by technical support from ESRI) and NOTHING IS WORKING.

Comment: You may want to consult ESRI Tech Support

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer somewhere on this forum.

Go to control panel - programs (uninstall) and click on `ArcMap`, then `Repair`.

After repair, everything will work. I think my CC Cleaner changed something in the registry.